# Stop file download in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Thanks in advance.

How can I stop downloading when some events occurred in wp7.For example when I am clicking a button named btnStop, all downloads should be terminated.

Comment: What are you using to do the downloads? WebRequest? WebClient? RestSharp? Other?

Comment: @ Pedro Lamas: I am using WebClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a download is still in progess and you wish to cancel it simply call [`CancelAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)